# Filter only rows that contain exact two strings in a column

Tags: r, string, filter, tidyverse, subset

I have a data.frame as follow:

`df = data.frame(sp_name = c("Xylopia brasiliensis", "Xylosma tweediana", "Zanthoxylum fagara subsp. lentiscifolium", "Schinus terebinthifolia var. raddiana", "Eugenia"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))`

Here's the deal: I am only interested in subsetting/filtering the rows from the df that contain **exactly** two words (in my case, Xylopia brasiliensis and Xylosma tweediana). How can I proceed? I'm failing miserably in using the `filter` function from `tidyverse`

Thanks already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `str_count` to create a logical vector in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    filter(str_count(sp_name, "\\w+") == 2)
```

-output

```
               sp_name value
1 Xylopia brasiliensis     1
2    Xylosma tweediana     2
```

---

Or this can be done with `str_detect` as well - match the word (`\\w+`) from the start (`^`) followed by a space and another word (`\\w+`) at the end (`$`) of the string

```
df %>%
    filter(str_detect(sp_name, "^\\w+ \\w+$"))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `grep`

```
subset(df, grepl("^\\w+ \\w+$", sp_name))
               sp_name value
1 Xylopia brasiliensis     1
2    Xylosma tweediana     2
```

Comment: I see! the \\w+ indicates that I want a match?

Comment: @hiperhiper if you check the `?regex` `The symbol \w matches a ‘word’ character`.  The `+` is to match one or more word character.  If I use `\\w` alone, it will match only the 'X' in Xylopia.  Basically, it is asking to match two words from the start to the end of the string in grepl or str_detect.  All other elements having either more or less than two words will not return TRUE

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thank you ver much.